# Open mysql php records in window.open

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What I'm trying to do is open records in window.showModalDialog depends on dropdown selected. My problem here is always the first value in dropdown is opens in new window.

How I can open record in new window depends on what I select on my dynamic dropdownlist?

```
<script>function modalWin() {
if (window.showModalDialog) {
window.showModalDialog("app_list2.php","name",
"dialogWidth:1550px;dialogHeight:1550px;");
} else {
window.open('app_list2.php','name',
'height=255,width=250,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no ,modal=yes');
}
}
</script>

<form action="app_list2.php" method="post" id="myform" onsubmit="modalWin(); return false;">
<select name="drop_1" id="drop_1" onchange="showUser(this.value)" style="overflow:scroll;width:100px;text-transform:uppercase;">
        <option value="ALL" selected='ALL'>ALL</option>
        <?php getTierOne(); ?>
</select>

    <span id="wait_1" style="display: none;">
    <img alt="Please Wait" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" width="15px" height="15px"/>
    </span>
    <span id="result_1" style="display: none;"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a hash as a variable when the window is opened? Like: `var hsh = $('#drop_1').val()`? Then you test for `location.hash.replace('#', '')` on the page you are opening with JavaScript to be cross Browser compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function modalWin(){
  var hsh = $('#drop1').val();
  if(showModalDialog){
    showModalDialog('app_list2.php#'+hsh,'name','dialogWidth:1550px;dialogHeight:1550px;');
  }
  else{
    open('app_list2.php#'+hsh,'name','height=255,width=250,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no ,modal=yes');
  }
}
```

Now on your the page you open:

```
if(location.hash.replace('#', '') === 'somevalue'){
  // do something accordingly
}
```

Note: `window` is implicit. You don't write `window.document.getElementById()`, do you?

Comment: I have 2 dropdownlist